# Div at the bottom of the page with scroll

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a div grow upwards from the bottom of the page. I've prepared an example to showcase the problem:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qEWemJ

As you can see, currently there is no scroll. I believe it's because I set the container positioning to fixed:

```
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0px;
```

I like the behavior (growing content from bottom up) however I need scroll. Any help is appreciated.

I am looking for a no-js solution.

Comment: [**codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VYZoWR) like this with `overflow:auto`

Comment: @vitorinofernandes this one does not have the button at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 3):

Add this on your container CSS (overflow-y and height)

```
#container{
   background-color: lightpink;
   padding: 50px;
   position: fixed;
   width: 100%;
   bottom: 0px;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   overflow-y : scroll;
   height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: this works well, I just noticed though, when the page starts to scroll it misses the button (button stays out of the scroll) -- is it possible to keep the scroll at the bottom, always?

Comment: @Zettam  This one works (but i dont think its working well on codepen) --> https://gist.github.com/mpalencia/575225c1cc2e27525733

Comment: I don't see it growing from the bottom of the page @mpalencia ?

Comment: oh terrible, how about this one (i added new div on the bottom of the button)-> https://gist.github.com/mpalencia/1bd95215741d33dbe537